# Recover saved passwords from 2018 version of Firefox

Tags: firefox, password-management, password-recovery, firefox-profile

I have an old Firefox profile copied from an old PC, which was last in use in 2018.  As far as I can tell, Firefox was at version 64 at the time.

Various resources talk about creating a new Firefox profile and copying the old password files into it.  But whereas current Firefox uses key4.db and logins.json to store saved passwords, the version I was using at the time uses key3.db and signons.sqlite, which don't seem to be compatible with current Firefox.

One such source says something like "Delete key3.db, key4.db and logins.json from your new profile, and copy the old versions of these files into the new profile", but I can't do this as the old profile has no key4.db file!  Copying just the files of these that do exist doesn't work.

I don't mind installing an old version of Firefox if I have to, but this brings me to the question of what I need to do to make sure the old version

- uses a separate profile
- doesn't try to upgrade itself
- doesn't interfere with the live Firefox version I am using

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you use a VM/Windows Sandbox to install the old 2018 version and import the profile with the saved passwords, then upgrade Firefox to the most current version, then export the updated profile?

Comment: Even in 2015 there was this [post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1076170) : "The key3.db file store the encryption key that is used for encrypting and decrypting the passwords. The encrypted names and passwords are stored in the logins.json file. The **signons.sqlite file is no longer used** in current releases since Firefox 32."

Comment: ... You need to copy the entire old profile to the profile folder of an 2018 Firefox installation.